# Remote debugging on server

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, remote-debugging

what is the best way to remote debugging .NET on server without install VS?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need to install all of VS on the remote server.
The VS installation disc contains a directory called Remote Debugger, which has two folders (x64 and x86) that contain the set-up application for the specific platform. This installs the remote debugging monitor (msvsmon.exe).

Of course, you'll still need Visual Studio on your local machine.

Comment: when i do remote debug website on server, it really slow.
so what is the best way?

Comment: Try to reproduce it locally. See if you can change your client applications to point to a locally running server, rather than remote server debugging.

Comment: i try locally it works fine. on the server has problem so i try to remote debug.